# Is it possible to get a method reference or function object from an object by reflection?

Tags: java, java-8

There is A class.

```
class A {
    Mono<Response> testMap(Mono<Request> reqMono)
}
```

There is the functional interface

```
interface MapHandler {
    Mono<?> handle(Mono<?> reqMono)
}
```

Now I can write this

```
{
A a = new A();
MapHandler handler = a::testMap;
}
```

And I want to build a tool that could detect **all** the MapHandler in a bean (object) and collect them.

I've tried this.

```
List<MapHandler> list = initedList;
Method method = bean.getClass().getDeclaredMethods()[0];
list.put("methodName", req -> {
    return (Mono<?>) method.invoke(bean, req);
})
```

Is it possible to do it by `MethodHandle` or `LambdaMetaFactory`?

Comment: You want to detect all methods in a certain bean that would conform to the declaration of `MapHandler`? Your code that you have 1) will not compile `invode` vs `invoke` 2) does not "test" if  that method complies to being a `MapHandler` - so care to make this a bit more clear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A rough sketch of a solution that explicitly uses `LambdaMetafactory` in the way you seem to want is:

```
// the signature of the method returned by LambdaMetaFactory
// it takes an object of bean's type and makes a MapHandler that calls one
// of its instance methods
MethodType mkLambdaType = MethodType.methodType(MapHandler.class, bean.getClass());
// the signature of the method in MapHandler being implemented
MethodType handleType = MethodType.methodType(Mono.class, Mono.class);
MethodHandles.Lookup lookup = MethodHandles.lookup();

// FYI this won't search in supertypes
// getMethods() will, but you only get public ones even if you have more privileged access
// you decide what to do here; the loop body is the important thing
for(Method method : bean.getClass().getDeclaredMethods()) {
    if(Modifier.isStatic(method.getModifiers())) continue;
    try {
        MethodHandle target = lookup.unreflect(method);
        CallSite mkLambda = LambdaMetafactory.metafactory
            (lookup, "handle", mkLambdaType, handleType, target, handleType);
        list.add((MapHandler)mkLambda.getTarget().invoke(bean));
    } catch(IllegalAccessException | LambdaConversionException e) {
        // because I am lazy, I'm not checking that method has the correct type
        // I'm letting LambdaMetafactory throw if that's not the case
        // if you choose not to use LambdaMetafactory, you may have to implement
        // this type-checking
        continue;
    } catch(Throwable t) {
        // Throwables come from the MethodHandle#invoke call
        // but nothing should be thrown at all, because LambdaMetafactory
        // produces its errors from metafactory, early, which are caught above
        throw new RuntimeException("Unexpected error during reflection", t);
    }
}
```

I believe this is very wasteful. A common implementation of `LambdaMetafactory` will likely create a whole new class in the `metafactory` call, returning a `CallSite` pointing to a constructor or similar. This means that each `MapHandler` you get is its own anonymous class, created at runtime. In contrast, your original idea of using a lambda to invoke a `Method` is much nicer to the JVM. The lambda causes the creation of a single `LambdaMetafactory` class, which holds `method` and `bean` as instance variables. After the first run through the code, where the `invokedynamic` is bootstrapped, each `MapHandler` is created simply by instantiating this anonymous class. My `LambdaMetafactory` solution only seems acceptable if you only need relatively few `MapHandler`s, but each is called so often that the overhead of `Method#invoke` is too high.

---

So I've gone ahead and done some quick benchmarking. In your use case, where you initialize `MapHandler`s at program start and then just invoke them, my technique and yours are about the same. They are both so fast that I cannot actually measure the difference in time taken to invoke the different kinds of `MapHandler`. In general, `LambdaMetafactory` is worse, because creating the anonymous class takes a lot of time. In fact, the more classes you make, the longer it takes. Meanwhile, the `method.invoke` lambda simply has to construct one object, which is often thousands of times faster.

Comment: > This means that each MapHandler you get is its own anonymous class.  
  
My solution that `() -> {}` wraps `method.invoke()` seems to do the same thing by LambdaMetafactory In compilation phase, but call the `Method#invoke`. 

> that the overhead of `Method#invoke` is too high.    
    
Your solution seems to reduce `Method#invoke` by creating a new `MapHandler`.

Comment: May I ask a new question?   

If I don't care about compilation performance and the performance of this tool,  
just care about whether the created function will affect performance because of reflection.  

Is it any difference between the created function of my solution and your solution?

Comment: Yes, this solution reduces the number of `Method#invoke` calls. No, that's not good enough to be faster than yours. Yours creates the *one* anonymous class. That class is generated at runtime, the first time the code is executed, and then reused. This *generates whole new classes __at runtime__ for __every__ `MapHandler`*. It is *ridiculously* expensive. Compilation performance is not related to this. Further, once you have a `Method`, calling `invoke` is only ~twice as slow as just calling the method. The real cost of reflection is looking up the `Method`, which takes 10x as long.

Comment: I'm not sure if the functional objects created by the `LambdaMetafactory` are faster than calling `method.invoke()`. I'm currently testing it.

Comment: If you’re calling `invoke` on the same `Method` object often enough, it will generate a new invoker class in the background too. An in-between solution is to use the direct `MethodHandle` returned by `unreflect` for the invocation. But since the question’s code snippets suggest that a `Map` from method name to actual invocation code will be maintained, I wouldn’t hesitate to use `LambdaMetafactory` generated classes, as the number will be finite, limited, and manageable…